# Fetch only one element from Graphql in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby

am new to gatsby and graphql and I came across a tutorial where it is mentioned to fetch all the data using `.map`. But I want to fetch only one element from the DB. So how do I do it?

```
import React from "react";
import Layout from "../components/layout";
import { useStaticQuery, graphql, Link } from "gatsby";

const Blogs = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
      query {
        allMarkdownRemark(sort: { frontmatter: { date: ASC } }) {
          edges {
            node {
              frontmatter {
                title
                date(formatString: "DD MM, YYYY")
              }
              excerpt
              id
              fields {
                slug
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
  );
  return (
    <Layout>
      <ul>
        {data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.map((edge) => {
          return (
            <li key={edge.node.id}>
              <h2>
                <Link to={`/blog/${edge.node.fields.slug}/`}>
                  {edge.node.frontmatter.title}
                </Link>
              </h2>
              <div>
                <span>
                  Posted on {edge.node.frontmatter.date} 
                </span>
              </div>
              <p>{edge.node.excerpt}</p>
              <div>
                <Link to={`/blog/${edge.node.fields.slug}/`}>Read More</Link>
              </div>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default Blogs;
```

Lets say I have multiple blogs and I wish to show only a specific one in a page through query like...

```
query MyQuery {
  markdownRemark((id: {eq: "9ac19d6d"}) //Some ID {
    title
    description
    content
  }
}
```

How to get this on a page to display?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what do you want to achieve:

- If you want just a specific single post. You can filter your `useStaticQuery` to add the value of the `id` (if you know it beforehand) like:

  ```
  query MyQuery {
     markdownRemark((id: {eq: "123"})  {
       title
       description
       content
     }
  }
  ```

  `useStaticQuery` as the name points out, is static and doesn't accept dynamic values.

  Another alternative is to get a specific position from `data.allMarkdownRemark` to display it.

  If you just want a single post without any filter you can take advantage of the GraphQL query options:

  ```
    {
      allMarkdownRemark(limit: 1) {
        edges {
          node {
            frontmatter {
              title
            }
          }
        }
      } 
    }
  ```
- If you are trying to create dynamic posts, hence each post template will display a different blog post (one per template), you need to pass a filter value from `gatsby-node.js` (where you create the post pages) to the template through Gatsby's context:

  ```
    // gatsby-node.js
    posts.forEach(({ node }, index) => {
      createPage({
        path: node.fields.slug,
        component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/blog-post.js`),
        context: {
          id: node.id, 
          title: node.title
        },
      })
    })
  ```

  *Note: here I'm lifting the `id` and the `title`. Use whatever works better for you*

  Now, you can take advantage of the context in your `Blogs` component (as long as it's a template):

  ```
     const Blogs = ({data}) => {
       console.log("your blog post is:", data)

        return (
          <Layout>
            <h1>{data.markdownRemark.title}</h1>    
          </Layout>
        );
      };

      export const query = graphql`
        query($id: String!, $title: String!) {
           markdownRemark((id: {eq: $id})  {
             title
             description
             content
           }
        }
      `

       export default Blogs;
  ```

In other words: the first approach uses a static query (via `useStaticQuery` hook. Static, no dynamic parameters allowed) and the second uses a page query (only available in pages or templates)

Answer (score 1):

With your query:

```
query MyQuery {
  markdownRemark((id: {eq: "9ac19d6d"}) //Some ID {
    title
    description
    content
  }
}
```

Your data will be in `data.markdownRemark`

You can access those 3 fields directly.

```
const { title, description, content ] = data.markdownRemark;
return (
  <Layout>
    <div>
      <p>{title}</p>
      <p>{description]</p>
      <p>{content}</p>
    </div>
  </Layout>
)
```